# aiohttp clientsession not staying logged in

Tags: python, python-requests, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I'm using aiohttp with ClientSession to create requests to login and after that, proceed to do other requests that require being logged in.

After some time digging and looking around, it seems like my session does requests as if it's not logged in. I'm really sure I'm logged in, since the cookies of the session are different when logged and not logged in.

It's also one of my first times using asyncio, aiohttp and Python classes at the same, cause before I would just call functions in the tasks and log in that way and back then the ClientSession did do logged in required requests fine.

Here is how my class looks like and how I create the ClientSession. The start function starts the whole process of the class, which is logging in and after that doing requests that require the user to be logged in.

```
class Task:
    def __init__(self, index, email, password):
        self.index = index
        self.email = email
        self.password = password
        self.session = aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=aiohttp.TCPConnector(ssl=False))

    async def start(self):
        await self.get_login_page()
        await self.get_profile_page()
        await self.session.close()
```

Here is how I start tasks with asyncio:

```
 loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
 task_object = Task(index, task_email, task_password)
 loop.create_task(task_object.start())
 loop.run_forever()
```

So right now I'm narrowing it down to how I wrote the code that affects the behaviour of the ClientSession, but I'm just not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it, my code was fine. aiohttp just doesn't handle redirects correct, so I switched to another http client.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: im using httpx rn